# Autocommands for Matlab in vim?

Tags: vim

I use several different programming languages every day, and I'd like to have different tab widths (in spaces) for each.  For example:  I use the "standard" 2 spaces for Ruby, but all our existing Matlab code uses 4 spaces.

I have this from my personal `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup lang_perl
    au!
    set tabstop=4 " tabstop length N in spaces
    set shiftwidth=4 " make >> and friends (<<, ^T, ^D) shift N, not the default 8
    set expandtab " Use spaces instead of tabs
augroup END

augroup lang_ruby
    au!
    set tabstop=2 " tabstop length N in spaces
    set shiftwidth=2 " make >> and friends (<<, ^T, ^D) shift N, not the default 8
    set expandtab " Use spaces instead of tabs
augroup END
```

Those work, but the following doesn't:

```
augroup lang_matlab
    au!
    set tabstop=4 " tabstop length N in spaces
    set shiftwidth=4 " make >> and friends (<<, ^T, ^D) shift N, not the default 8
    set expandtab " Use spaces instead of tabs
augroup END
```

I really don't understand how `augroup lang_ruby` figures out that I'm editing a Ruby file.  (My searches brought up `ftdetect`, but the solution wasn't obvious.)  It doesn't seem like `vim` knows that I'm editing Matlab using `augroup lang_matlab`.  What do I change to make this work?

Comment: When you are editing a matlab (.m) file, and you type `:set filetype?`, does it respond with `filetype=matlab`?  It's possible it's identifying your .m files as another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a large number of settings for {filetype}, you should put them into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` or into file that matches `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}/**/*.vim` (examples: `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby/foo.vim`, `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby/foo/bar.vim`). In this case you don't need any autocommands at all. If you still want to use autocommands, use the following:

```
augroup lang_matlab
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType matlab      setlocal ts=4 sw=4 et
augroup END
```

. Note two things: FileType event (it is there and it is not BufRead,BufNewFile) and `setlocal` instead of plain `set`. First is intended to be used for filetype settings, second is how buffer-specific options must be set.

About why perl and ruby settings work and why matlab settings does not: your example code is just the same as

```
augroup lang_perl
    autocmd!
augroup END
augroup lang_ruby
    autocmd!
augroup END

set tabstop=4 " tabstop length N in spaces
set shiftwidth=4 " make >> and friends (<<, ^T, ^D) shift N, not the default 8
set expandtab " Use spaces instead of tabs

set tabstop=2 " tabstop length N in spaces
set shiftwidth=2 " make >> and friends (<<, ^T, ^D) shift N, not the default 8
set expandtab " Use spaces instead of tabs
```

So, you effectively set `ts=2 sw=2 et`. But the `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/perl.vim` contains the following code:

```
setlocal  tabstop=4
setlocal  shiftwidth=4
```

so, `ts=4 sw=4` for perl is set into `ftplugin/perl.vim`, **not** in your vimrc (if you have installed perl-support plugin). You can check it by replacing `tabstop=4` with `tabstop=8` in vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you how it's determined that `lang_perl` or `lang_ruby` shall be read. But looking at the autocommand documentation brings up an example for gzipped files (`:he gzip-example`):

```
augroup gzip
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre       *.gz set bin
  autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost     *.gz '[,']!gunzip
  autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost     *.gz set nobin
  autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost     *.gz execute ":doautocmd BufReadPost " . expand("%:r")
  autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost   *.gz !mv <afile> <afile>:r
  autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost   *.gz !gzip <afile>:r
  autocmd FileAppendPre                *.gz !gunzip <afile>
  autocmd FileAppendPre                *.gz !mv <afile>:r <afile>
  autocmd FileAppendPost               *.gz !mv <afile> <afile>:r
  autocmd FileAppendPost               *.gz !gzip <afile>:r
augroup END
```

See it? Every `autocmd` that gets specified carries an Event (`BufReadPre`, `FileReadPre`) and the extension for which it shall be executed (`*.gz`). This is backing up my hitherto opinion that you can use any name for your `augroup` but have to specify an extension that the `augroup` shall be responsible for in order to get it working correctly.

Another quote of `:he autocmd-groups`:

> Normally, when executing autocommands automatically, Vim uses the autocommands
>   for all groups.  **The group only matters when executing autocommands with
>   ":doautocmd" or ":doautoall", or when defining or deleting autocommands.**

So, in order to make an `augroup` for matlab files, this one should do the trick:

```
augroup lang_matlab
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead       *.m set ts=4 sw=4 expandtab
augroup END
```

And make sure that these settings don't get overwritten by any `augroup`s that do something unconditional (i.e. modify the other `augroup` definitions too).

Comment: `autocmd BufRead       *.m set ts=4 sw=4 expandtab` contains two errors: 1) use `setlocal` for filetype-specific settings like any plugin in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin` does; 2) don't redo job already done by `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`: use `FileType matlab` instead of `BufRead *.m`.

Comment: @ZyX: Since the settings being set here (ts, sw, expandtab) are buffer-local, it shall be no problem I think. And *error* is IMHO a too big word.

Comment: @ZyX: And if the answer not 100% correct, I can at least claim that **it works** and I brought back the question that was starving around since March last year :-)

Comment: it is problem when you start editing a new file in current vim session and expect to see default settings from your vimrc, but in fact you see settings for matlab.

Comment: By the way, `*.m` extension designates one of `objc`, `matlab` or `mma` filetype, not only matlab. `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` knows about this, your script does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use ftplugins, configuring vim will be much more easier to achieve.
See [gVim and multiple programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404515/gvim-and-multiple-programming-languages)