# Vim: Shortcuts specific to a file extension?

Tags: vim, shortcut

In Vim, it is possible to attach syntax highlighter to a file extension.

Is it possible to do the same with keyboard shortcuts?

I.e. the shortcuts would switch on only if a file with particular extension is being edited.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/47793/vim-hotkeys-for-specific-file

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404515/gvim-and-multiple-programming-languages/1404570#1404570 (There is a link from Stefan's SU page to this one.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The association is not directly to file extensions, but *filetypes* (which can be detected based on file extensions, but also other file patterns or even its contents). `:setl filetype?` shows you the current buffer's.

To define a filetype-specific mapping, just append the `<buffer>` attribute after the `:map` command. (Same for custom commands, use `-buffer` after `:command`.)

You can define that for certain filetypes by prepending `:autocmd Filetype {filetype} ...`, and put that into your `~/.vimrc`. But that gets unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes. Better put the commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_mappings.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)